# Diagram / Infographic of TeX & friends?

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files

So, I recently delved into LaTeX for a project at work.  But I’m come from the XML+XSL world, and some of LaTeX’s design is kind of difficult for me to grok.

(I’m not interested in debating the design decisions of separation of semantics from presentation. I’m just saying that my brain is used to thinking in a very different way, and I’m having a hard time forming a mental model of how LaTeX-and-friends all work together to accomplish their task.)

I’m a visual thinker.  Is there a diagram that describes what the typical LaTeX processing flow is?

For example, imagine an article written in LaTeX, which makes use of BibTeX references.  I know there are also `.sty` files in the processing, somewhere.  I also spotted some `.aux` files.  And while browsing the packages installed by [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) I recall reading that some packages can even define their own filetypes for custom functionality.  Among these types of files, what are the most popular formats?

So when I open a LaTeX document in my GUI editor and hit *Typeset*, and up pops a PDF—what has just taken place?  (And more importantly, what are the responsibilities of each component in the processing chain?)

Comment: http://www.zapata.org/stuart/latex/bibtex.shtml includes Figure 12.1 from The LaTeX Companion. Maybe the book includes some figure that better illustrates the compilation process. http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~c603/latex/latex.php includes a simple image of the compilation and `\include`. Also, if you want to know about the different files, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics#Files_you_might_Encounter. Maybe it would make sense for someone to make a nice flow chart of the compilation process and also share the code for it?

Comment: Also see figure 1.1 and 1.2 in http://people.ksp.sk/~kuko/tex/latex/Wetherell,%20Chris%20-%20LaTeX1.pdf, the figure in http://franz.kollmann.in/latex/latex.html#preface, http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LaTeX_diagram.svg

Comment: [TeX-workflow](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tex-workflow/)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Based on [this example on texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/interaction-diagram/)
I have created this diagram: [image: Infographics: Interaction of User level and Software/file level in LaTeX workflow]

This infographic is an attempt to visualize the interaction of 'User level' and 'Software/file level' in LaTeX workflow.
Sources available [here](http://wpage.unina.it/agodemar/temp/latex_user_sw_levels.zip).

This is not exactly an answer. To give an idea of the files involved in the compilation, the node named ".tex file" should be elaborated further. There should be more nodes on the "Software/file level"---e.g. ".sty file(s)", ".aux file(s)", ".tex file(s)", etc.---each one connected to the main .tex source node. This makes the infographic more complicate. Moreover, the diagram really would depend on the particular case. Similarly, if the chain latex|dvips|ps2pdf is used, also other nodes, e.g. ".ps file", should show their dependence on other files in the TeX system (.pro files, etc).

Comment: Very nice! I showed your diagram on my blog - [LaTeX workflow](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/latex-general/latex-workflow/).

Comment: +1, but I hope that one day "dvi" does not appear in diagrams like these anymore. "Why is TeX so hard to use? Because it creates output you need a special viewer for".

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz - Cool! You can put this diagram in the gallery of examples at TeXample.net

Comment: @agodemar Gladly! I added the diagram and a link to TeX.SX to the [diagram example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/interaction-diagram/), where it's based on.

Comment: @Patrick Gundlach - I agrre with your comment. Actually the picture could be simplified very much if we consider the actual standard, i.e. working with pdflatex (even when using pstricks). But then, probably, there's no need anymore for a two-level representation.

Answer (score 17):

Not regarding the LaTeX processing flow, but dependencies of LaTeX, TeX and related software, still matching the title of your question and your visual thinking:

[An overview of TEX, its children and their friends](https://github.com/alt/tex-overview) by Arno Trautmann is an overview with a many diagrams.

- It deals with the difference between engine, format and distribution
- Gives a short and an comprehensive diagram of the TeX program and the descendants
- Provides diagrams of various formats (plain TeX, LaTeX, related)
- Shows the development of ConTeXt
- Lists other formats
- Gives an overview of current and historical TeX distributions
- Deals with MetaPost, BiBTeX, Fonts, and more, in a visual way

The source code is available on https://github.com/alt/tex-overview.

An example tree diagram, showing TeX engines with code dependencies, also trying to keep it in a chronological order:

[image: Tex engines tree]

Comment: I really like the `iTeX` block totally unrelated to any other. Well... It is...!

Comment: I would love to display this graph in an intro LaTeX class under the heading ``\TeX\ is easy!'' :) [Of course it's not really related to how you produce final documents, but they wouldn't know]

Comment: I am not sure why ant has a line to TeX. It is as much related to TeX as chocolate ice cream.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach it is ANT as in "Ant is Not Tex" by Achim Blumensath not as in the tool from apache

Comment: @FrankMittelbach sure, but it is not related to TeX. Otherwise you could probably also mention RTF, lout and probably many others.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach well the connection is that its implementation was inspired by TeX which makes it a good reason to be put into a history tree. That's not the case for RTF afaik, but you are right there are probably others that should be listed too for that reason.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach RTF looks so much like TeX that it is too much of a coincidence if it wasn't just copied TeX.

Comment: @Patrick you may well be right in which case I think there is a good point for Arno to add this to his diagram. But it would be good if there is some collaboration on this other than wikipedia stating it listing any source